# One airlfow job is much slower than another one with same code base

Tags: python, airflow

I have two exactly the same airflow jobs with the same code base. The only difference is that they are writing data to different Mongo collections.

One of the jobs is ~ 30% slower than another, how is it possible? May Airflow allocate for one job more resources than for another?

Answer (score 0):

If both use the same queues, have same priority and are always run in the same environment there should be no visible difference. Unless one of the jobs is run in different time and load on the system at that moment is higher. Is this duration difference a visible trend?

Have you tested performance of those jobs outside Airflow? Size and complexity of the collections may also matter.